# How to get a XML block in Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to rearrange / combine XML files to a new target file.

My data has the following form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Level1>
  <Level2>
    <Level3>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>String1</Name>
      <Attribute>123</Attribute>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>String2</Name>
      <Attribute>456</Attribute>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>String3</Name>
      <Attribute>789</Attribute>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>
```

I'm looking for a python command to get a block of Level3 via the ID, for example

getBlock(2) should deliver

```
<Level3>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Name>String2</Name>
  <Attribute>456</Attribute>
</Level3>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example of using ElementTree, but without doing all of the unnecessary for loops. The testing of the `ID` value can be done in a simple [XPath predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates).

**Example** (super basic with no error checking)

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<Level1>
  <Level2>
    <Level3>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>String1</Name>
      <Attribute>123</Attribute>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>String2</Name>
      <Attribute>456</Attribute>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>String3</Name>
      <Attribute>789</Attribute>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

def getBlock(xml_tree, id):
    return xml_tree.find(f".//Level3[ID='{id}']")

print(ET.tostring(getBlock(tree, "2"), encoding="unicode"))
```

this will print:

```xml
<Level3>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Name>String2</Name>
  <Attribute>456</Attribute>
</Level3>
```

If you'd like to use more complicated XPath, I'd recommend [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) since [ElementTree's XPath support is limited](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

Comment: Thanks also to you - that is what I will use. I had a look at the documentation before, but could not manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's XML library to do this. The following is a code snippet to show one way of obtaining an XML block based on its children's value.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Parse XML file, creates ElementTree object
tree = ET.parse("<XML_FILEPATH_HERE>")
root = tree.getroot()

# Get <Level3> nodes with specific id within XML ElementTree object
def getBlock(root, id_value):
    for lvl_3 in root.findall('.//Level3'):
        if id_value == lvl_3.find('ID').text:
            print(ET.tostring(lvl_3).decode())
```

You can check out the python XML library document for more information.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

The [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) package can do that for you.

Import your data from either string or file

```
Level1 = ET.fromstring(myXml)
```

And you'll have a tree in the form of a list of lists.

Iterating, selecting or filtering over these lists becomes easy.  This iterates across a list of all Level3 elements:

```
Level1 = ET.fromstring(myXml)

for Level3 in Level1.findall('.//Level3'):
    for child in Level3:
        print (child.tag, child.text)
```

Comment: Thank you - what an elegant solution this is as well